# Git Rebase: Adding files after directory structure changed

Tags: git, directory, structure, rebase

I have the following scenario:

I have Repo1 and I created a copy of it in Repo2, by cloning Repo1 and then changing the origin to Repo2. So far so good. No in Repo 2 I want to create a src folder and move all the files into it, such that we have the following situation:

Repo1:

```
- file1
- folder1
  -file2
```

Repo2:

```
-src
  - file1
  - folder1
    -file2
```

So far so good. No when I **rebase Repo2 onto Repo1**, and file1 has changed, it detects this and adds the changes to the correct file1 inside the src folder of Repo2.

**The problem is when I add a file in Repo1 and then rebase it does not detect this and puts the new file outside the src folder.**

Any tips on how this could be solved such that smooth rebasing will be possible?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Git does not manage directories, only individual files. You'll need to script around it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the first commit in *Repo2* that's not in *Repo1* is moving the files into the subdirectory:

```
git switch -c tmp repo-1/master
git rm -r *
mkdir src
git read-tree --prefix=src -u HEAD
move_commit=$(git rev-list repo-1/master..master | tail -1)
git commit --no-edit -c $move_commit
git rebase --onto tmp $move_commit master
git branch -d tmp
```

Or if you don't insist on rebasing, you could do either of these:

- `git merge -s subtree repo-1/master`
- `git subtree pull --prefix=src repo-1 master`